# Django - objects.values() and prefetch_related() in same query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Book, Profile, Book_stat model as below. I am trying to minimize the fields from `Book` model and prefetch_related method to get the data from `Book_stat` model.

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="mp/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Book_stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title + ' by: ' + self.user.profile.full_name
```

**views.py**

```
def books(request):
    books = books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('book_stat_set').values('id','title', 'image')
    for book in books:
        for book_stat in book.book_stat_set.all(): # error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'book_stat_set'
            book.stats = book_stat
            pprint(vars(book_stat))
    return HttpResponse(books, content_type= 'json')
```

**1)** I would like to send the `json response` to front end as below
**2)** If possible i want to use `book_stat_set.values('like', 'rating')` instead of `book_stat_set.all()` so that i query for `like`, `rating` only

```
books = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'some title1',
        image: 'image1.jpg',
        stats: {
            like: true,
            rating: 3.50
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'some title2',
        image: 'image1.jpg',
        stats: {
            like: true,
            rating: 3.50
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You should probably be using django-rest-framework, which has support for nested serializers.

Comment: yes, but this is the only time i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead the `values` method you can use the `only` and serialize manually:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.forms import model_to_dict
from django.http import JsonResponse

def books(request):
    prefetch = Prefetch('book_stat_set', queryset=Book_stat.objects.only('like', 'rating'))
    qs = Book.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch).only('id','title', 'image')
    result = []
    for book in qs:
        row = model_to_dict(book, fields=['id','title', 'image'])
        row['image'] = row['image'].url
        stats = []
        for book_stat in book.book_stat_set.all():
            stat = model_to_dict(book_stat, fields=['like', 'rating'])
            stat['rating'] = str(stat['rating'])  # or float(stat['rating']) - depends on your purposes
            stats.append(stat)
        # you can calculate an average rating here
        row['stats'] = stats
        result.append(row)
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

Comment: thanks, it gives me invalid json response try to use json validator `{'title': 'Testing', 'stats': [{'rating': Decimal('3.80'), 'like': True}, {'rating': Decimal('3.50'), 'like': True}], 'image': <FieldFile: mp/bruce_lee_quote.jpg>, 'id': 1}{'title': 'Testing 2', 'stats': [{'rating': Decimal('3.50'), 'like': False}], 'image': <FieldFile: None>, 'id': 2}` no `,` after each object and not inside `[]` why was that?

Comment: `FieldFile` and `Decimal` fields require additional serialization. I updated code in the answer, please check.

Comment: also I added `JsonResponse` from django

Comment: Thanks it worked, do you recommend anything to learn in-depth about django ORM apart from django documentation.

Comment: for me django documentation is the best source of knowledge last years :) for example today I read about `django.db.models.Prefetch`. maybe good books about django exists, but unfortunately I don't know

Answer (score 1):

If you need it only once you can serialize it by hand.

```
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('book_stat_set')

books_json = [{
    'id': book.id,
    'title': book.title,
    'image': book.image.url,
    'stats': [
        {
            'like': stat.like, 'rating': str(stat.rating)
        } for stat in book.book_stat_set.all()
        ]
} for book in books]
```

Comment: i am getting 'dict' object has no attribute 'id' as well as with `title` and `image` so i replaced `book.id` with book['id'] and other as well, then i got 'dict' object has no attribute `'book_stat_set'`

Comment: Are you maybe confused with what books has to hold,  tested this in Django console and it works

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, i am getting error as `'Book' object is not subscriptable`